# Android getWidth, getHeight, getLeft, getRight not correct after setScaleX() , setScaleY()

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop, zooming

I try to implement the zoom in/out by spread/pinch gesture and the drag and drop functions on a Relative Layout.

This is the code of my OnPinchListener to handle the zoom effect.
The **mainView** is the RelativeLayout defined in the layout xml file.

I implement the touch listener in the **fakeview** which should be in front of all view. The touch event will change the **mainview** according to the code.

**I want to ask if it is possible to get the actual left, top, width and height after the scale?** It always return 0,0 for left and top, and the original width and height after zoom.

Thanks very much!

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/zoomable_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
          <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>




public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //ZoomableRelativeLayout mainView = null;
    RelativeLayout mainView = null;
    RelativeLayout rl = null;
    public static final String TAG = "ZoomText."
            + MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private int offset_x;
    private int offset_y;
    private boolean dragMutex = false;
    RelativeLayout fakeView = null;
    float width = 0, height = 0;
    private OnTouchListener listener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            // Log.e(TAG, event + "");
            // Log.e(TAG, "Pointer Count = "+event.getPointerCount());
            Log.e(TAG,
                    event.getX() + "," + event.getY() + "|" + mainView.getX()
                            + "(" + mainView.getWidth() + "),"
                            + mainView.getY() + "(" + mainView.getHeight()
                            + ")");
            if (event.getX() >= mainView.getLeft()
                    && event.getX() <= mainView.getLeft() + mainView.getWidth()
                    && event.getY() >= mainView.getTop()
                    && event.getY() <=mainView.getTop() + mainView.getHeight())
                if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                    return scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                } else {
                    return llListener.onTouch(arg0, event);
                }
            return false;

        }

    };

    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    private OnTouchListener llListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Log.d(TAG, event + ",LL");
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                offset_x = (int) event.getX();
                offset_y = (int) event.getY();
                // Log.e(TAG, offset_x + "," + offset_y);

                dragMutex = true;
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//              Log.e(TAG, "Finger down");
                int x = (int) event.getX() - offset_x;
                int y = (int) event.getY() - offset_y;
                Log.e(TAG, event.getX() + "," + event.getY());
                float _x = mainView.getX();
                float _y = mainView.getY();
                mainView.setX(_x + x);
                mainView.setY(_y + y);
                offset_x = (int) event.getX();
                offset_y = (int) event.getY();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                dragMutex = false;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };
    private OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View arg0, DragEvent arg1) {
            Log.e(TAG, "DRAG Listener = " + arg1);
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoomable_relative_layout);
        // mainView.setOnTouchListener(new OnPinchListener());
        // mainView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,
                new OnPinchListener());
        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        mainView.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
        // mainView.setOnTouchListener(llListener);
        fakeView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        fakeView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    }

    class OnPinchListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        float startingSpan;
        float endSpan;
        float startFocusX;
        float startFocusY;

        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            startingSpan = detector.getCurrentSpan();
            startFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
            startFocusY = detector.getFocusY();
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
//          mainView.scale(detector.getCurrentSpan() / startingSpan,
//                  startFocusX, startFocusY);
//          if(width==0)
//              width = mainView.getWidth();
//          if(height==0)
//              height = mainView.getHeight();
            mainView.setPivotX(startFocusX);
            mainView.setPivotY(startFocusY);  
            mainView.setScaleX(detector.getCurrentSpan() / startingSpan);
            mainView.setScaleY(detector.getCurrentSpan() / startingSpan);  

//          LayoutParams  para = mainView.getLayoutParams();
//          width*=detector.getCurrentSpan() / startingSpan;
//          height*=detector.getCurrentSpan() / startingSpan;
//          para.width = (int)width;
//          para.height = (int)height;
//          mainView.setLayoutParams(para);


            return true;
        }

        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            //mainView.restore();
            mainView.invalidate();
            Log.e(TAG, mainView.getLeft()+","+mainView.getRight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change "event" with "v", like event.getX to v.getX.

Comment: Thanks! I just got 0,0 while getting v's X,Y. The code   "Log.e(TAG, event.getX() + "," + event.getY()); " is changed to Log.e(TAG,"ACTION_MOVE:"+ v.getX() + "," + v.getY());

Comment: yes this is because your view is filling the parent (as it seems from the xml). GetX means pixel from left side of the view. GetY means pixels from the top. If its filling up the parent then definatly its edges would be touching the top,left corner.

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the transformation matrix and use that to transform your original points.

so something like this (after you do the scaling):

```
Matrix m = view.getMatrix(); //gives you the transform matrix
m.mapPoints(newPoints, oldPoints); //transform the original points.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it in my case (`getViewRect` should be called after view was laid out, for example through `view.post(Runnable)`, so `view.getWidth()/getHeight()` returns actual values):

```
public static Rect getViewRect(View view) {
    Rect outRect = new Rect();
    outRect.right = (int)(view.getWidth() * getScalelX(view));
    outRect.bottom = (int)(view.getHeight() * getScalelY(view));
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);
    return outRect;
}


public static float getScalelX(View view) {
    float scaleX = view.getScaleX();
    view = getParent(view);
    while (view != null) {
        scaleX *= view.getScaleX();
        view = getParent(view);
    }
    return scaleX;
}

public static float getScalelY(View view) {
    float scaleX = view.getScaleY();
    view = getParent(view);
    while (view != null) {
        scaleX *= view.getScaleY();
        view = getParent(view);
    }
    return scaleX;
}

public static ViewGroup getParent(View view) {
    if (view == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
    if (parent instanceof View) {
        return (ViewGroup) parent;
    }
    return null;
}
```

however it just turned out that android 3.1 (probably 3.0 also) doesn't take in account scale factor while dealing with `getLocationOnScreen` method. 
I'm gonna to manually scale the rect before returning it from my `getViewRect(View)` function in case of android 3.1 api like this:

```
public static void scaleRect(Rect rect, float scaleX, float scaleY, float pivotX, float pivotY) {
    rect.left = (int) ((rect.left - pivotX) * scaleX + pivotX);
    rect.right = (int) ((rect.right - pivotX) * scaleX + pivotX);
    rect.top = (int) ((rect.top - pivotY) * scaleY + pivotY);
    rect.bottom = (int) ((rect.bottom - pivotY) * scaleY + pivotY);
}
```

However one should know a pivot coordinates for every view in the hierarchy from the current view to the root and corresponding zoom levels to handle this transformation correctly.

If someone has any straightforward solution it will be appreciated

**EDIT:**

This is how I modified the `getViewRect(View)` method so it works on 3.1 also:

```
public static Rect getViewRect(View view) {
    Rect outRect = new Rect();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
        outRect.right = (int)(view.getWidth() * getScalelX(view));
        outRect.bottom = (int)(view.getHeight() * getScalelY(view));
        int[] location = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);
    } else {
        outRect.right = view.getWidth();
        outRect.bottom = view.getHeight();
        int[] location = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);
        View parent = view;
        while(parent != null){
            parent.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            scaleRect(outRect, parent.getScaleX(), parent.getScaleY(), parent.getPivotX() + location[0], parent.getPivotY() + location[1]);
            parent = getParent(parent);
        }
    }
    return outRect;
}
```

I think `if`- clause could be removed so that the second branch (`else`) should work for all versions. However I prefer to use straightforward solution (the first branch of the `if`) so that the second is just a workaround :)